# convert a mixed binary string represantation back to binary

Tags: python, string, hex, representation

I have a binary string representation of some (former) binary file created by python `str()`.

The string (or actually the file the string is stored to) looks like

```
some\nexample\x00text'with"all\xbe\xa1Dsorts\\of[itchy%chars
```

So we have ascii, escape sequences, hex escape sequences and all sorts of itchy ascii chars like quotes.

Is there any way, to convert this file back to the actual binary?

**Edit 1:**
The file is actually the result of a `fd.write(str(dict(bottle.request.forms)))`.
The bottle request dictionary contains multiple entries, one of which has a pdf file as value.

Comment: May you elaborate more on what you mean by "binary file created by python str"?

Comment: @abukaj See my edit :)

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the dictionary? You may try to use `eval()`, but I am pretty sure that it will not work because of the PDF file.

Comment: use a proper output format, e.g. `pickle`.

Comment: @abukaj No. the result of `str(dict(forms))` was written to a file. I now want to transform the line `'PDF': '<some pdf data>'` back to an actual pdf.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The file is already there. I don't have the bottle http request which was used to create the file anymore. The expected result is apdf ;)

Comment: @Uroc327: You can not. '<some pdf data>' contains no actual PDF data - seems just to be a stub indicating, that PDF data was there.

Comment: @Uroc327: Hmm... Is it you who replaced actual content of the string with 'some pdf data'?

Comment: @abukaj yep, that was me. In the actual file, there is the representation of the actual pdf of course.

Comment: Oh, then you just need to extract the string and write it to a file. Unless you performed any encode/decode calls it is the binary... Given that you are not using Windows - in which case I simply do not know.

Comment: @abukaj Well, I extracted the string and it looks like stated in the question. It is not binary (that's what I want as a result) but everything that is not printable ascii (escape sequences, unicode, ...) is encoded (`\n`, `\x00`, ...).

Comment: Try to print it (with `print` function/command) - do you see `\n` or new lines?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112811/discussion-between-abukaj-and-uroc327).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is not encoded, the encoding is for display purposes only.

Printing it with `print` function/command will print its content.